Detect first login of a user on keycloak
I want to detect if the user is logging in for the time on keycloak, by a boolean field like first_login in the token claims which could be set to true when the user logs in for the first time. I could not find any relevant predefined mapper nor a user attribute here to create a new custom mapper.
Is there a way to do that?

You can do this with a custom Event Listener SPI:

Add the custom user attribute first_login with a value of true or false.

Create a new protocol mapper to add this attribute to your token claims.

Implement a custom event listener SPI to listen to the user's login event and modify their first_login attribute:


public class FirstLoginEventListener implements EventListenerProvider {
    private final KeycloakSession session;

    public FirstLoginEventListener(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.LOGIN) {
            String userId = event.getUserId();
            var user = session.users().getUserById(session.getContext().getRealm(), userId);

            String firstLoginAttr = user.getFirstAttribute("first_login");
            if (firstLoginAttr == null) {
                user.setSingleAttribute("first_login", "true");
            } else if (firstLoginAttr.equals("true")) {
                user.setSingleAttribute("first_login", "false");
            }
        }
    }
}

Reference

Keycloak Event Listener SPI
EventType (Keycloak Docs Distribution 24.0.3 API)

